# Raster and digitized shapefile misplaced in same projection

Tags: qgis, raster, arcmap, coordinate-system

I have georeferenced .tiff rasters with cadastral borders and corresponding digitized borders in shapefile based on that raster. All that was done in some Mapsoft software. When I insert both in QGIS in same projection WGS84/UTM, they are slightly misplaced for some 0.5 m in NW-SE direction, same is in ArcMap. Any hint why that hapenning?

Comment: I bet that one software is using top-left corner of the pixel as an anchor point while the other is using the centre of the pixel. Do your raster images have pixel size of 1 m?

Comment: sounds likely. A quick way to check is to run `gdalinfo yourraster` and check the values of `PIXEL SIZE` and `AREA_OR_POINT`. I believe you can change the latter setting by using `gdal_translate -mo` to create a new copy with the opposite setting.